# How to handle CORS requests in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, web-services, cors

I'm facing problem with CORS requests in AngularJS while calling web services but the same service able to call by using jQuery.

Note: From server side we are receiving header **"Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*"** and these services are running fine in jQuery application.

Here I'm posting my AngularJS code as well as jQuery code.

AngularJS:

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url:  $rootScope.host + "UserLogin",
        //headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        data: {
            "uname": $scope.uname,
            "password": $scope.password
        },
    }).then(function (success) {
                $scope.loginDetails = success;
                console.log($scope.loginDetails);
    }),function (error){
            console.log(error);
});
```

If I pass the header like `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }` able to ping the service but my request is not going in JSON format.

If I change the header to `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`, getting

> **XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://XXXX.XXXX.in/XXXXAPI/UserLogin**.

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://170.11.0.61' is therefore not allowed access.

I don't know what is the reason for this error.

```
$.ajax({
    url: BASE_URL + "UserLogin",
    type: "POST",
    xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    data: {
        "uname": uname,
        "password": password
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function (result, textStatus, request) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log("Error in login service call:"+JSON.stringify(e));
    }
});
```

This jQuery is sending my request in the json format.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass headers like

```
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
```

Comment: If I changed my header, My service call not pinging the server and showing "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://XXXX.XXXX.in/XXXXXAPI/UserLogin. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://172.16.0.61' is therefore not allowed access."